# razor/WebMatrix variable scope

Tags: razor, webmatrix-2

I have this in my webpage

```
@{
    if(!IsPost){
        var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
        var catList= db.Query("select * from category");    
    }
    else{
        var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
        var query = "insert into product (productkey,productname,categorykey) values(@0,@1,@2)";
        ....more code....
    }
}
```

In my html I have the following

```
<select id="categorySelect" name="Name">
@foreach(var cat in catList){
    <option value=cat.CategoryKey>@cat.CategoryName</option> 
}
</select>
```

Problem is that when navigating to this page the first time I get this CS0103 exception saying that The name `catList` does not exist in the context

I am loading this page from a link in another page. What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define catList in if(){...} statement so you get this error, predefine it before **if**.

```
dynamic catList=null;
if(!IsPost){
var db = Database.Open("MyDatabase");
catList= db.Query("select * from category");
...
```

Comment: Hey thanks Aleksey, just one clarification to those facing the same problem. catList variable should be declared with type dynamic instead of IEnumerable to avoid generic type exception: 
dynamic catList=null